# Replace special characters and white space in response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I have a response with special characters that is coming from the back-end. Here is the response that if am getting form back-end.

Note: This response is coming from Dynamic stored procedure (PIVOT Table) form, so the response is having dynamic keys. Based on the parameters we are passing to the response the keys will be changed. We won't get same JSON keys every time. JSON response contains two columns, sometimes it contains 9 columns.

---

```
[
        {
    "Layer_Nbr": "4",
    "Barbican B [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": "1",
    "BESIM [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  1:47PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:10PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:11PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:17PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:18PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:26PM]": null
    },
    {
    "Layer_Nbr": "5",
    "Barbican B [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": null,
    "BESIM [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  1:47PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:10PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:11PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:17PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:18PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:26PM]": null
    },
    {
    "Layer_Nbr": "6",
    "Barbican B [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": null,
    "BESIM [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  1:47PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:10PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:11PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:17PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:18PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:26PM]": null
    },
    {
    "Layer_Nbr": "7",
    "Barbican B [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": "1",
    "BESIM [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  1:47PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:10PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:11PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:17PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:18PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:26PM]": "1"
    }
        ]
```

I am consuming that response through my service

```
getProgramCurvePivot(Key: number, ScenarioKey: number): Observable<any>  {
    return this._http.get(ENDPOINT + 'GetProgramCurvePivot/?id=' + Key + '&param1=' + ScenarioKey)
        .map((response: Response) => 
            <any>response.json())
        .catch((err) => { throw err; });
}
```

and I am subscribing to that response in programComponent

```
getProgramCurve() {
        this.Service.getProgramCurvePivot(this.Key, this.ScenarioKey)
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.programCurvedata = response;
            },
            error => {
                this.loggingService.sendToServerError(error);
            });
    }
```

I am trying to replace white spaces and special characters from the JSON response keys, since the kendo grid is not accepting the field headers with special characters and white spaces, thus throwing a warning as it is not valid Javascript identifier.

Can you help me how to replace the special characters and white spaces in the array (`this.programCurvedata`) when I am subscribing the response in my component?

I am using ***kendo grid ui angular*** ***in cell editing***.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-8" *ngIf="programCurvedata">
    <kendo-grid #grid [data]="programCurvedata" [resizable]="true"
    (cellClick)="cellClickHandler($event)"
    (cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)" >
        <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let item of getProgramNameList();let index=index" width="23%" 
        title="{{item}}" field="{{item}}">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <div> {{ dataItem[item] }}&nbsp; </div>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
</div>

 getProgramNameList() {
        if (this.programCurvedata.length) {
            const programList = Object.keys(this.programCurvedata[0]);
            programList.splice(0, 1);
            return programList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will strip out all non-alphanumeric characters, so more robust than just removing whitespace...

```js
var data = [{
    "Layer_Nbr": "4",
    "Barbican B [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": "1",
    "BESIM [Dec 28 2017  2:47PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  1:47PM]": null,
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:10PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:11PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:17PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:18PM]": "1",
    "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:26PM]": null
}];


// parse the object's properties - add one with a safer name and delete the old one
function makeObjectKeysSafe(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        var newKey = key.replace(/\W/g, "");
        obj[newKey] = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
    });
}

data.forEach(function(o) { makeObjectKeysSafe(o); });

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, It works as expected ,but I need to display the column header to user in such a way that is coming from backend  "TPRET18 Ba [Dec 28 2017  2:26PM]"

Comment: Thank you I was able to display in UI with original keys @Archer